# How do i set the checkbox item checked after refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webmethod, hidden-field

I have a dropdowncheckbox and the hiddenfield value.The hidden field values are 1,3,4,5.So I want to set dropdowncheckbox to be checked after postback in jquery for related hiddenfield values.How do I do that?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var Statushdn = document.getElementById('<%= hdnSubCategoryId.ClientID%>').value;
    var str_array = Statushdn.split(',');
    var summar;
    $.each($('#ContentPlaceHolder1_ddcbProductStockSubCategory_dv input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)'), function() {

        summar = $(this).val();
        for (var i = 0; i < str_array.length; i++) {

            if (str_array[i] == summar)
                $(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: a cookie or pass it in query string apart from that a server side language would be needed.

Comment: are you using update pannel??

Comment: store your required values in session and then call that session value in entire application anywhere you want to call until that session value get clear or changed..

Answer (score 1):

You can use localstorage to keep the values from checkboxes like:

```
$(':checkbox').on('change', function () {
    //set the check value of checkbox
    localStorage.setItem(this.id, this.checked);
});

$(':checkbox').each(function () {   
    //retrieve the checked value from the checkboxes and 'convert' it to bool
    var status = localStorage.getItem(this.id) === "false" ? false : true;
    $(this).prop("checked", status);
});

<input type="checkbox" id="chk1" />
<input type="checkbox" id="chk2" />
<input type="checkbox" id="chk3" />
<input type="checkbox" id="chk4" />
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vue7hcan/)

References:

[Window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: actually I have the values which are in hiddenfield.But I want those hidden filed values to be set into the checkbox checked after postback.

Comment: But hidden fields loose their values after postback or you retrieve them from a database?

Comment: but when i debugging the javascript in console they retrieve the hiddenfiled values.But there is some problem in the $.each(function() .Please look at my above code and if you have any idea please tell me to correct.